# Showing webpage content with newline character

Tags: php, regex, newline

I parse webpage content and show it in the div in following way:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach($xpath->query("//script") as $script) {
    $script->parentNode->removeChild($script);
}

$textContent = $doc->textContent; //inherited from DOMNode
$text=escapeshellarg($textContent);

$test = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", " ", html_entity_decode($text));
```

But this also removes newline characters(paragraphs) into $test. 
How can I include newline char in above so that each paragraph are visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include newlines simply by not replacing them.

```
$test = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z\n]+/", " ", html_entity_decode($text));
                               ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a nice function for it. Try this:

```
echo nl2br($test);
```

Comment: thanks, but it skips newline characters. Here is my code review please http://codetidy.com/6796/